# Ionic Select, change default selected option from script

Tags: ionic-framework, html-select, default

I'm facing a problem with ionic select options. In a settings popup, I defined a few options and one is `selected="true"` like the following code:

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="changeStartpoints($event)" interface="popover">
  <ion-option value="1" selected="true">1</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="2">2</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This works perfectly fine, but now I don't want the first option to be selected by default every time I open the settings popup. If the second option was selected the last time, I want the second option to be pre-selected this time opening the popup.

I tried this:

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="changeStartpoints($event)" interface="popover">
  <ion-option value="1" selected="isSelected_Startpoints(170)">1</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="2" selected="isSelected_Startpoints(501)">2</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

where `isSelected_Startpoints()` is:

```
isSelected_Startpoints (value: number) {
  console.log(this.startpoints);
  if (this.startpoints == value) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and `changeStartpoints()` is:

```
changeStartpoints (change) {
  change = parseInt(change);
  this.startpoints = change;
}
```

but it did not work. Not even the `console.log` appeared.

So my question is, **Is it possible to link functions to the "selected" attribute? And how can I solve my problem?**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like this a try:

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="changeStartpoints($event)" interface="popover">
    <ion-option value="1" selected="{{startpoints === 170}}">1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2" selected="{{startpoints === 501}}">2</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

My guess is your version may have worked if you changed your `selected` to `[selected]` too